# RuntimeException. Как вывести в консоль сообщение об ошибке?

Tags: java, исключения

Всем привет! Есть такой кусок кода -

```
if (!checkValidationCircle()) {
    throw new NotCircleException("Круг не существует! Проверьте параметры круга!");
}
```

NotCircleException это мною созданное исключение, которое я наследовал от Exception, затем ловил его в try-catch и с помощью

```
System.out.println(e.getMessage())
```

выводил это сообщение в консоль. Теперь я решил отнаслдеовать мое исключение от RuntimeException и таким образом избавиься от try-catch, но НЕ ЗНАЮ ТЕПЕРЬ как сделать так, чтобы это сообщение так же хорошо выводилось в консоль, а не красной записью как теперь...

Answer (score 2):

`RuntimeException` и все его дочерние классы это непроверяемые исключения (англ. *unchecked exceptions*), для них не является обязательным блок `try-catch`, но это не означает, что выполнение программы продолжится после возникновения этого исключения.

В вашем случае, после выбрасывания исключения `NotCircleException`, которое является *unchecked*, выводится StackTrace (точно так же, как если бы в `catch` блоки вы вызвали `e.printStackTrace()`) и выполнение текущего потока завершается.

Идея "избавления" от блока `try-catch` может быть ошибочной, так как если вам нужно обработать это исключение и вывести пользовательское сообщение, то вы должны использовать проверяемые исключения (англ. *checked exception*) и блок `try-catch`.

Из документации Oracle:

> Generally speaking, do not throw a RuntimeException or create a subclass of RuntimeException simply because you don't want to be bothered with specifying the exceptions your methods can throw.
>
> Here's the bottom line guideline: If a client can reasonably be expected to recover from an exception, make it a checked exception. If a client cannot do anything to recover from the exception, make it an unchecked exception.

Comment: Т.е. никак нельзя сделать так - чтобы исключение было непроверяемым и без try-catch вывести пользовательское сообщение?

Comment: @Жаважуниор красное оно потому что ваше IDE подсвечивает, так то оно точно также вываливается в консоль. Если вам очень не нравится красный цвет уверен это можно поправить в настройках IDE, ну или вернуть try-catch и выводить через System.out.println